# "select" in Racket

Tags: networking, scheme, racket

I want to write an event loop single threaded web server to deal with each request in Racket.
I see there are select method in unix that I can call, 
Is there anything similar in Racket API that I can call?  or I should write my own select method which is to polling the ready fds?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you'll probably want to use tcp-listen on certain ports; success here will create input ports.  In order to synchronize on multiple open input ports, check out "synchronizable events"; you can use 'sync' on a whole bunch of open ports simultaneously.

I would be remiss if I failed to add that there's a complete web server included with Racket; I'm assuming that you have your own reasons for wanting to re-implement this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will check that out. (and expecting more examples in the doc anyway :). and yes, for research or pure personal interest, I am curious to write one from scratch :)

Comment: followup question: but if use sync on some input port, for example, on the in stream from a client, the doc says: Blocks as long as none of the synchronizable events evts are ready, which means that it is still blocking...while I want a non-blocking IO, how can I do that??

Comment: Take a look at 'sync/timeout' with a timeout of zero.  The docs specifically stipulate that this is an effective polling technique.

Comment: oh...Thanks for the reminder....I remembered that when I was new here, I clicked that thing but the system told me I have not enough privileges to do that, and since that, I just forgot to do it!